# TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len() when using a custom metric in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am developing a model for multi-class classification problem ( 4 classes) using Keras with Tensorflow backend. The values of `y_test` have 2D format:

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
```

This is the function that I use to calculate a balanced accuracy:

```
def my_metric(targ, predict):
    val_predict = predict
    val_targ = tf.math.argmax(targ, axis=1)
    return metrics.balanced_accuracy_score(val_targ, val_predict)
```

And this is the model:

```
hidden_neurons = 50
timestamps = 20
nb_features = 18

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
                units=hidden_neurons,
                return_sequences=True, 
                input_shape=(timestamps,nb_features),
                dropout=0.15
                #recurrent_dropout=0.2
              )
         )

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=round(timestamps/2),activation='sigmoid')))

model.add(Dense(units=hidden_neurons,
               activation='sigmoid'))


model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=nb_classes,
               activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics = [my_metric],
              optimizer='adadelta')
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        30 model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
>        31               metrics = [my_metric], #'accuracy',
>   ---> 32               optimizer='adadelta')
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights,
>   sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
>       449                 output_metrics = nested_metrics[i]
>       450                 output_weighted_metrics = nested_weighted_metrics[i]
>   --> 451                 handle_metrics(output_metrics)
>       452                 handle_metrics(output_weighted_metrics, weights=weights)
>       453
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in
>   handle_metrics(metrics, weights)
>       418                     metric_result = weighted_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred,
>       419                                                        weights=weights,
>   --> 420                                                        mask=masks[i])
>       421 
>       422                 # Append to self.metrics_names, self.metric_tensors,
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py
>   in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
>       402         """
>       403         # score_array has ndim >= 2
>   --> 404         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
>       405         if mask is not None:
>       406             # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in Theano
>
> in my_metric(targ, predict)
>        22     val_predict = predict
>        23     val_targ = tf.math.argmax(targ, axis=1)
>   ---> 24     return metrics.balanced_accuracy_score(val_targ, val_predict)
>        25     #return 5
>        26
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py
>   in balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, adjusted)
>   1431     1432     """
>   -> 1433     C = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)    1434     with
>   np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):    1435
>   per_class = np.diag(C) / C.sum(axis=1)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py
>   in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight)
>       251 
>       252     """
>   --> 253     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>       254     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
>       255         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py
>   in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>        69     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
>        70     """
>   ---> 71     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
>        72     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
>        73     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
>   check_consistent_length(*arrays)
>       229     """
>       230 
>   --> 231     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
>       232     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
>       233     if len(uniques) > 1:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
>   (.0)
>       229     """
>       230 
>   --> 231     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
>       232     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
>       233     if len(uniques) > 1:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
>   _num_samples(x)
>       146             return x.shape[0]
>       147         else:
>   --> 148             return len(x)
>       149     else:
>       150         return len(x)
>
> TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()

Comment: `metrics.balanced_accuracy_score` is this from sklearn?

Comment: @Primusa: Yes. `from sklearn import metrics`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot call a sklearn function on a Keras tensor. You'll need to implement the functionality yourself using Keras' backend functions, or TensorFlow functions if you are using the TF backend.

The `balanced_accuracy_score` is defined [as the average of the recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html) obtained in each column. Check [this link](https://gist.github.com/dgrahn/f68447e6cc83989c51617571396020f9) for implementations of precision and recall. As for the `balanced_accuracy_score`, you can implement it as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K

def balanced_recall(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Computes the average per-column recall metric
    for a multi-class classification problem
    """ 
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)), axis=0)  
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)), axis=0)   
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())    
    balanced_recall = K.mean(recall)
    return balanced_recall
```

Answer (score -5):

try :

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`